# How to make checkbox is checked by default

Tags: xml, module-params

I'm trying to add checkbox to my template parameter and giving default="1" value to make it checked by default.

```
<field name="fieldname" type="checkbox" label="fieldlabel" description="Desc of the field" value="1" default="1"/>
```

The output indeed checked by default by it can't be unchecked. Everytime I uncheck it and save the parameter, the checkbox is always back to checked.

If I change the default value to 0 then it's working properly. Any idea how to deal with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been discussed on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725937/joomla-php-checkbox-wont-uncheck), and as far as I can see there aren't any simple solutions. A couple of options are discussed, so you might be able to implement something. The OP of the question ended up creating a field override.

The problem is really a HTML shortcoming, explained [here](http://planetozh.com/blog/2008/09/posting-unchecked-checkboxes-in-html-forms/).

> Submitting it, leaving empty values and not checking the checkbox, you
>   would get the following $_POST array (notice the missing "checkbox")
>
> ```
> array (
>   "input" => "",
>   "hidden" => ""
> )
> ```
>
> In short: `<input type="checkbox" name="field" value="something">`
>   either gets submitted as `field = "something"` if checked, or doesn't
>   exist if unchecked.

<sup>http://planetozh.com/blog/2008/09/posting-unchecked-checkboxes-in-html-forms/</sup>